# Video is not playing on local Machine in visual studio using unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

[image: Code]

I have added code in Unity to play video , which is woking in Unity , but when I export the Unity code in to Visual Studio .sln file, Video is not playing , other objects are rendering. When tries to run on local machine it shows white space instead of video.

Any help will be really appreciable , I am new to Unity and MSVisualStudio.
[
[[image: Local machine screenshot]2]]

Comment: Have you read though the documentation yet? http://unity3d.com/partners/windows/hololens, or more specifically https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/unity_development_overview, once you do that you play the video the same way you would play any other video in Unity.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have seen the tutorials , its working on Unity but unable to run on visual studio after exporting.

Also Edit my question for clarity

Comment: what does it means  "export the Unity code in to Visual Studio"?

Comment: After putting the code in Unity , we need to build the written code on to windows emulator or local machine , for that Unity provides a way to convert your script and code , to visual studio .sln file. So we can deploy it.

Comment: Which platform are you building it for, before exporting to visual studio?

Comment: @ Anmol Mahatpurkar Unity

Comment: @ManiaChamp can you somehow send me a sample project. May upload on github

Answer (score 0):

Check unity's video player menu .

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are referring to Win10 (Windows Store) application? If so, that should use [Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html), I don't think the standalone mode it would work.

Comment: Yes but I have created the Scene in Unity and write script there to play video.Its working fine in Unity but I need to add in windows application.

Comment: @ManiaChamp what do you mean foe "windows application"? If you mean a Windows Store (Win 8.1 or Win 10) then you should use the Handheld class because your code is meant to run on standalone, not on win store apps.